# Xarray Distributed Failed to serialize

Tags: dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I need to upsample through a linear interpolation some satellite images organized in a DataArray.
Until I run the code locally I've no issue but, if I try to replicate the interpolation over a distributed system, I get back this error:

```
`Could not serialize object of type tuple`
```

to replicate the problem what's needed is to switch between a distributed or local env.
here the distributed version of the code.

```
n_time = 365
px = 2000 
lat = np.linspace(19., 4., px)
lon = np.linspace(34., 53., px)
time = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=n_time, freq='D')
data = xr.DataArray(np.random.random((n_time, px, px)), dims=('time', 'lat', 
'lon'),coords={'time': time, 'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})
data = data.chunk({'time':1})

#upsampling 
nlat = np.linspace(19., 4., px*2)
nlon = np.linspace(34., 53., px*2)
interp = data.interp(lat=nlat, lon=nlon)
computed = interp.compute()
```

Does any have and idea on how to work around the problem?

EDIT 1:

As seems that I haven't been enough clear in my first MRE so I decided to rewrite with all the inputs received up to now.
I need to upsample a satellite dataset from 500 meters to 250m.  The final goal is, as chunking along the dimension to be interpolated is not yet supported **, figure out how I can create a workaround and upsampling each image to the 500 datasets.

```
px = 2000
n_time = 365
time = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=n_time, freq='D')

# dataset to be upsampled
lat_500 = np.linspace(19., 4., px)
lon_500 = np.linspace(34., 53., px)
da_500 = xr.DataArray(dsa.random.random((n_time, px, px),
                      chunks=(1, 1000, 1000)),
                      dims=('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                      coords={'time': time, 'lat': lat_500, 'lon': lon_500})

# reference dataset
lat_250 = np.linspace(19., 4., px * 2)
lon_250 = np.linspace(34., 53., px * 2)
da_250 = xr.DataArray(dsa.random.random((n_time, px * 2, px * 2),
                      chunks=(1, 1000, 1000)),
                      dims=('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                      coords={'time': time, 'lat': lat_250, 'lon': lon_250})

# upsampling
da_250i = da_500.interp(lat=lat_250, lon=lon_250)

#fake index
fNDVI = (da_250i-da_250)/(da_250i+da_250)

fNDVI.to_netcdf(r'c:\temp\output.nc').compute()
```

This should recreate the problem, and avoid to impact on the memory as suggested by Rayan. In any case, the two datasets can be dumped to the disk and then reloaded.

**note seems that something is moving to implement an interpolation along with chunked dataset but isn't still fully available. Here the details   https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/4155

Comment: I tried this and didn't see any issue.  I set `n_time = 3` and `px = len(lat)`.  Maybe upgrade to latest version of libraries if you can ?

Comment: With small numbers, the problem doesn't pop up. Try to increase the values but don't forget that in some cases you will hit the limit of the memory before the one from the serialization.

Comment: Can you provide reasonable numbers ?

Comment: In my case 2000 and 365 recreate the problem. 
The original dataset is much bigger in the space dimension ( 3000x5000) but less in the time's one  (280)

Comment: I ran for some time (5+ minutes) and while the process did not finish I didn't get any error.  Does this occur early on in the process ?   Have you tried updating to latest versions of the libraries ?

Comment: No, it takes quite some time as it has to create the dummy dataset. 
Yes all the libraries are all updated 
Python 3.8 all pkgs updated to the latest conda-forge vrs.
NOTE ! that if you don't run on a cluster everything goes smoothly. The issue appears only on teh distributed version.

Comment: I tried running this yesterday but ran out of time waiting for data generation to complete -- is it possible to narrow this down to some which can run in 1-2 minutes ?

Comment: I tested with lower values and everything seems ok so I would bet that there is a problem with a higher spatial dimension. Have you tried with a lower time resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are two things that cause this example to crash, both likely related to memory usage

- You populate your original dataset with a large numpy array (`np.random.random((n_time, px, px)`) and then call `.chunk` after the fact. This forces Dask to pass a large object around in its graphs. **Solution**: use a lazy loading method.
- Your object `interp` requires 47 GB of memory. This is too much for most computers to handle. **Solution**: add a reduction step before calling compute. This allows you to check whether your interpolation is working properly without simultaneously loading all the results into RAM.

With these modifications, the code looks like this

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as dsa
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

n_time = 365
px = 2000 
lat = np.linspace(19., 4., px)
lon = np.linspace(34., 53., px)
time = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=n_time, freq='D')

# use dask to lazily create the random data, not numpy
# this avoids populating the dask graph with large objects
data = xr.DataArray(dsa.random.random((n_time, px, px),
                    chunks=(1, px, px)),
                    dims=('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                    coords={'time': time, 'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})

# upsampling 
nlat = np.linspace(19., 4., px*2)
nlon = np.linspace(34., 53., px*2)
# this object requires 47 GB of memory
# computing it directly is not an option on most computers
interp = data.interp(lat=nlat, lon=nlon)

# instead, we reduce in the time dimension before computing
interp.mean(dim='time').compute()
```

This ran in a few minutes on my laptop.

Comment: You have a point on memory and I decided to rewrite the MWE to make more clear what's the problem I'm facing

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edited question, I have a new solution.

In order to interpolate across the lat / lon dimensions, you need to rechunk the data. I added this line before the interpolation step

```py
da_500 = da_500.chunk({'lat': -1, 'lon': -1})
```

After doing that, the computation executed without errors for me in distributed mode.

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
fNDVI.to_netcdf(r'~/tmp/test.nc').compute()
```

I did notice that the computation was rather memory intensive. I recommend monitoring the dask dashboard to see if you are running out of memory.